# Overloading the '++' operator for a scoped enum class type

Tags: c++, enums, operator-overloading

I've been experimenting with the enum class feature of C++ and successfully got the `++` operator to overload as follows:

```
enum class counter_t : uint8_t {VAL1 = 0, VAL2, VAL3, VAL4, END};

inline counter_t operator ++ (counter_t c, int) {
  counter_t c2;
  if (c == counter_t::END) {
    c2 = counter_t::VAL1;
  }
  else {
    c2 = (counter_t)((uint8_t)c + 1);
  }
  return (c2);
}

int main(void) {

  volatile counter_t x = counter_t::VAL1;
  x = x++;
  x++;

  while(1) {
    // Do stuff
  }
}
```

It is fairly straightforward. The "x=x++;" line works fine, however the "x++;" line does not. What is the correct form of the ++ operator function for the autoincrement version?

Comment: take argument `counter_t c` via reference and modify it

Comment: Umm... the `++` operator only takes one operand, doesn't it? Why do you have `counter_t` *and* `int`?

Comment: @Jashaszun It depends, prefix increment does not take an extra argument, but the postfix operator takes an extra dummy `int` argument, so it have a different function signature from the prefix operator.

Comment: Can you explain how it is "not working"?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ah thanks for the explanation. It's been too long since I've done C++.

Comment: Isn't `x = x++;` still undefined, even if `operator++` is overloaded?

Comment: @jxh Nope, it's valid to write `x = operator++(x,0);` and therefore valid to write `x = x++;`.  Function calls have more sequencing restraints than built-in operators.

Comment: I should note that I'm doing this in GNU C++ on the Atmel AVR Atmel Studio 6.2.

Comment: @aschepler: Another reason C programmers fear C++.

Comment: Sorry, NathanOliver: the code compiles with no errors and loads into the debugger, but the "x++;" autoincrement doesn't execute, indeed it's ignored entirely. I've been assuming that it's because I don't have the proper overload function, but it could be a GNU bug.

Comment: Jashaszun: yes, this is the postfix operator, so the overload requires the dummy int parameter to distinguish it from the prefix operator.

Comment: jxh: no, the equality operator still works for assignments within the type.

Answer (score 4):

You may use this to implement a prefix increment:

```
inline counter_t& operator ++ (counter_t& c) {
  if (c == counter_t::END)
      c = counter_t::VAL1;
  else
      c = counter_t(unsigned(c) + 1);
  return c;
}
```

Now, you can use the prefix increment to implement the postfix increment:

```
inline counter_t operator ++ (counter_t& c, int) {
  counter_t result = c;
  ++c;
  return result;
}
```

Test:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(void) {
    counter_t prefix = counter_t::VAL1;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << unsigned(++prefix) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';

    counter_t postfix = counter_t::VAL1;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
        std::cout << unsigned(postfix++) << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Note: In each case the counter is taken by reference and gets modified.

Answer (score 3):

Just following the errors, the following code compiles runs and works fine on [MSVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B). Note the `volatile` and `&` in function parameters. Also `c2 = c` and a couple of modifications, to follow the `++` standard (return value, then increment). `volatile` is necessary only because you have x declared as `volatile`.

```
inline counter_t operator ++ (volatile counter_t &c, int)
{
    counter_t c2;

    if (c == counter_t::END)
        c2 = counter_t::VAL1;
    else
        c2 = static_cast<counter_t>(static_cast<uint8_t>(c) + 1);

    c = c2;

    return c2;
}
```

Comment: You fail to follow standards with `x++`. it should be `{auto old = c; ++c; return old;}` and use your function for `++x`.

Comment: The volatile was in there to keep the compiler from optimizing the program to nothing (even at -O1). I turned it down to no optimization, and don't need the volatile.

Comment: Hey, that works!. I thought that the pass-by-reference should be in there somewhere, but didn't know about the static_cast. Thank you very much.

Comment: `static_cast` isn't important in this case. I bothered me because I had it underlined in VS as an warning "C style cast instead of C++". Try to avoid C style cast, they can be problematic sometimes.